# Is there a chance that street and zipcode data wasn't enough to populate full address

Tags: forms, zipcode

I have a form where I ask the user to input their mailing address. Would there be any issues with asking only street address and zipcode and omitting city and state? 
User zipcode in conjunction with zipcode database would result in having full address of the user. Would that be reliable considering that zipcode database is accurate?

Comment: For which country is your database? In France and Australia, zip codes can be shared by different cities for example.

Comment: Besides the reasons already listed in the various answers, accepting the city provides a crosscheck against typos in the ZIP.  For example, a common address like 1 MAIN ST exists in many ZIP codes, and a single-digit error in the ZIP will lead to the wrong address in the wrong city.  Also see [this discussion](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/cgi/zip5.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcin,
There is not a one to one relationship between city and zipcode.  A city can have multiple zipcodes.  A zipcode can cross city lines.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that.

- A ZIP code can contain two different towns, each with a "#123 Main Street" address.
- A ZIP code may cross state lines, which means you don't have enough information for shipping/tax details.
- You'll have a very hard time dealing with any customers who live outside of the USA.